# Silverlight OOB strange behaviour with Fiddler

Tags: silverlight, prism, mef, fiddler, silverlight-oob

I have a Silverlight app I've composed with Prism using MEF to dynamically load modules.

When I take this app out of browser I experience some strange behaviour!

If fiddler happens to be running when I load my SL app, the modules load as expected and everything works fine. However if fiddler is not running I just get a plain white box as none of my modules are loaded.

I assume this has something to do with the references I have in my module catalog to the .xap files? But I don't understand why running fiddler would mean my module catalog functions correctly.

Any help in deciphering this is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2010/11/22/fiddler-and-silverlight-cross-zone-cross-domain-requests.aspx ?

Comment: Also, what are your proxy setting set to when Fiddler *isn't* running? IIRC, there's a known issue with "Automatically Detect" where it may not work properly depending on system ACLs, because the WPAD script fails to get written.

Comment: @EricLaw-MSFT- Had no luck still after fiddling around with my proxy settings. Put this issue on hold as a similarly composed app is working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When fiddler is capturing it modifies the Internet Options proxy settings it insert itself as a proxy.  At times things can get confused so that when Fiddler is not capturing what should be temporary settings are left in place.  Normally though you'll notice all your IE usage is broken.

Check your Internet Options Proxy settings on that machine whilst Fiddler is not run to confirm the settings are what you expect.

Failing that the app may have captured to the proxy settings when installed as OOB it will then want to use Fiddler as proxy all the time.  If checking your proxy setting shows up nothing untoward try uninstalling as OOB then reinstalling while Fiddler is not running.

Comment: That helped slightly! I now get my shell displaying, but my modules still aren't loaded unfortunately.

Comment: @James: do the modules load when Fiddler is running but not when it isn't?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Yes! For some reason best know to themselves they load perfectly fine when Fiddler is on the go.